# Problem with Raspberry cam

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

I've mounted the raspi cam v1.3 onto my Raspberry Pi zero, enabled It via raspi-config ,when I run raspistill the window pops up for 5 sec showing the camera view but then if I try to run sudo I get /usr/bin/sudo cannot execute binary. Seems like the raspistill corrupted sudo. Has anyone ran in this problem? Could be an hardware problem?

Comment: `if I try to run sudo I get /usr/bin/sudo cannot execute binary` What exactly are you trying to do. How is this related to `raspistill`?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.* -- Please explain the situation much more clear.

Comment: After a fresh install of raspbian I run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade without problem. After I ran raspistill whatever command I try to run using sudo I get the error.